# Insert records in database in which have 3 foreign keys

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to insert a record in the table but the problem is in that table have 3 foreign keys. I'll be using dataTable for that but it gives an error 'There is no row position at 0'

There is my code:

```
 try
        {
            using (var sqlConnection = new Helpers.SqlConnectionHelpers())
            {
                var connection = sqlConnection.OpenConnection();


                command = new SqlCommand("CarSold_Insert", connection);
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                SqlCommand commandTwo = new SqlCommand("SELECT CarForSaleId, UserId, SalesPersonId FROM CarSold WHERE Price = '" + txtPrice.Text + "'", connection);
                DataTable table = new DataTable();
                DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
                table.Load(commandTwo.ExecuteReader());
                var carForSaleId = table.Rows[0]["CarForSaleId"].ToString();
                var userId = table.Rows[0]["UserId"].ToString();
                var salesPersonId = table.Rows[0]["SalesPersonId"].ToString();

                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("CarForSaleId", carForSaleId);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("UserId", userId);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("SalesPersonId", salesPersonId);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Price", txtPrice.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("DateSold", dateSold);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("MonthlyPaymentDate", monthlyPaymentDate);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("MonthlyPaymentAmount", txtPaymentAmount.Text);
                //connection.Open();
                int k = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                command.Parameters.Clear();
                if (k != 0)
                {
                    Response.Redirect("~/AdminPanel/CarSold.aspx");
                }
                else
                {
                    lblAns.Text = "Record Not Inserted into the database";
                    lblAns.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblAns.Text = ex.Message;
        }
```

Comment: what i understand from your code is you are trying to get the same record you are inserting into database, for that you should run command.ExecuteNonQuery(); before the select statement.

Comment: No, I'm not trying to insert same records it's just the foreign key that I have to fetch from it.

Comment: @PratikshaPansara Is Price column datatype varchar? I noticed your query is `SELECT CarForSaleId, UserId, SalesPersonId FROM CarSold WHERE Price ='{txtPrice.Text}'`. Ensure that above select statement is returning one or more rows

Comment: Datatype of Price column is Float

Comment: Then you need to fix the select query `SqlCommand commandTwo = new SqlCommand("SELECT CarForSaleId, UserId, SalesPersonId FROM CarSold WHERE Price = " + txtPrice.Text, connection);`

Comment: Some tips: SqlCommand is IDisposable so should be in a `using` block. Avoid string concatenation to create queries because it makes your code vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, and SQL syntax errors - use parameters. You may want to read [can we stop using AddWithValue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). You could process the DataReader much simpler than cramming it into a DataTable and ripping values out as strings without checking whether there were any rows. When asking about an error, state which line the error occurred.

Comment: It is done using the drop-down list, I try to fetch record but I want to insert records so, in the foreign key, I use the drop-down list and then it should be done.

Answer (score 0):

Since Price column is float you need to write query with query parameter like this:

```
SqlCommand commandTwo = new SqlCommand("SELECT CarForSaleId, UserId, SalesPersonId FROM CarSold WHERE Price = @Price", connection);
commandTwo.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", txtPrice.Text);
```

The above mentioned command will give return you the `carForSaleId`, `userId`, `salesPersonId` which you will use in the insert command

Comment: It's not working, because I fetch the Id but I want to insert records.

Comment: The issue is that your `commandTwo` sqlCommand is not returning any data based on the Price value that you are using as filter criteria. Ensure that there is data against the price value that you type into the `txtPrice` textbox